# Diffeomorphism group vs local $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: group-theory, smooth-manifolds

I am typically on the physics stack exchange but thought this question was more appropriate here. If there is any terminology that is unclear in what follows please let me know!

I'd like to understand the difference between the diffeomorphism group $\text{Diff}(M)$ which acts on a smooth manifold $M$ and the local general linear group (I will call it $GL(TM)$) which acts on the tangent bundle $TM$. Let's consider the group elements of $GL(TM)$ to be smooth functions.

In this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism#Lie_algebra), it is stated that

> The diffeomorphism group of Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ consists of two components, consisting of the orientation-preserving and orientation-reversing diffeomorphisms. In fact, the general linear group is a deformation retract of the subgroup $\text{Diff}(\mathbb{R}^n, 0)$ of diffeomorphisms fixing the origin under the map $f(x) \to \frac{f(tx)}{t}, t \in (0,1].$ In particular, the general linear group is also a deformation retract of the full diffeomorphism group.

This is referring to the "global" general linear group. Is there any way to precisely state the difference between these two groups?

Comment: In the result you quote, $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is acting on $\mathbb{R}^n$ itself, not on the tangent spaces; this is why it can be considered a subgroup of $\operatorname{Diff}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. This isn't really related to the general linear groups of the tangent spaces, and doesn't have an obvious analogue on a general manifold.